# Left Outer Join with IEnumerable

Tags: entity-framework-4

using Entity Framework 4.1 is it possible to perform a left outer join with an IEnumerable?

For example, lets say i want to count the number of orders for each month.

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(1,6).AsQueryable();
var result = range
               .GroupJoin(context.Orders, i => i, o => o.Month, new 
               {
                   Month = i, 
                   Count = m.Count()
               });
```

Which would produce the following

```
Month, Count    
1, 0
2, 0
3, 10
4, 20
5, 0
6, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you call `context.Orders.ToList()` and load all orders to your application. `IEnumerable` is in your application memory and `context.Orders` represent data in your database. You cannot join data in database with data in memory of your application. Converting `IEnumerable` by `AsQueryable` will not put it to database.

To do your requirement directly with ADO.NET and SQL you must either create and fill temporary table and perform a database join or create stored procedure with table valued parameter to perform database join. Neither technique is supported by EF.

Comment: I guess that is sort of true but if you consider the reverse it is possible by creating a union of enumerable values. Just need a right outer join, not a left outer join http://blog.hompus.nl/2010/08/26/joining-an-iqueryable-with-an-ienumerable/